# Run long operation after dismissing modal UIViewController

Tags: ios

I am starting a long-running operation on a UIViewController presented modally. What's the best way to dismiss this UIViewController but still finish the operation in the background?

Comment: Be WAY more specific in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep a strong reference to the controller somewhere so it doesn't get deallocated when you dismiss it. You would probably want to do this in the presenting view controller, by creating a property for the controller you're about to present.